# Center of Mass using Line Integrals v.s. Triple integrals

Tags: calculus, integration

What is the difference between these two formulas?(Below) One uses triple integrals and the other uses a single line integral. How do I know when to use which? Maybe I'm not grasping the concept as this might be a trivial question.

Also, what are the formulas for the MOMENTS around each axis for the triple integrals and the line integrals?

Line integral: https://i.stack.imgur.com/9ihj5.jpg
(formula for line integral is simply the same as triple but with one integral only)

Triple integral : https://i.stack.imgur.com/9ihj5.jpg#1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The helix is a space curve, so you use line integrals in the first link. In particular,   the helix is parametrized with only one parameter. If the mass is described with three parameters (like a ball or the inside of a cylinder), then you use triple integrals.

Comment: @Shet was there something you didn't understand?

Comment: Well you answered most of my question, I'm just wondering what the formula for the moments are for each integral. My teacher never told us in class but its required for our assignments.

Comment: @Shet for a 3-dimensional body of density $\delta$, the moment of inertia about a line $L$ is $I_L = \iiint r^2(x,y,z)\delta(x,y,z)\, dV$, where $r(x,y,z)$ is the distance from $(x,y,z)$ to $L$. For instance, if $L$ was the $x$-axis, then $r(x,y,z) = \sqrt{y^2 + z^2}$, and the inertia about the $x$-axis is then $I_x = \iiint (y^2 + z^2)\delta(x,y,z)\, dV$.

Comment: Thank you, and what about for line integrals? I assume it would be the same thing? I found Iz = integral (x^2+y^2) rho(x,y,z)ds on yahoo answers. Edit: Yes i think what I wrote is correct.

Comment: @Shet yes, it would be the same concept. And yes, you've got the correct formula (assuming $ds$ represents the volume element) for the moment of inertia about the $z$-axis.